# How to add bookmarks exactly at the location near a page's edge in Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, adobe-acrobat

In a PDF file, sometimes a header is located near the line between two pages. In this condition, if I added a bookmark to mark this heading, Acrobat will automatically adjust it to the line instead of the heading.

How to remove this sticking setting or to reduce the sticking area?